# Tab-index to move left-to-right then to down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

We have created an application in AngularJS HTML. In this the tab order on text boxes, links, buttons, and other objects should be left-to-right. Once the right-most object on the row is reached, the tab should go down and to the left-most text box.

To achieve this I have added tab-index on element, but as per the requirement I need left-to-right movement.

One sample code added below :

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">
   <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="field_Name">Name <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
         <input tab-index="0" required type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" id="field_Name"
            ng-model="vm.Name"
            ng-maxlength="255"/>
         <div ng-if="myForm.Name.$invalid">
            <p class="help-block"
               ng-if="myForm.Name.$error.maxlength">
               This field cannot be longer than 255 characters.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Upload Sample File</label>
         <input tab-index="2" type="file"
            name="file"
            id="uploadSampleFile"
            ng-model="vm.File"
            ngf-select
            accept="file_extension"
            ngf-min-size="5000">
         <div ng-if="myForm.file.$invalid">
            <p class="help-block" ng-if="myForm.file.$error.minSize">File size should be greater than 5 KB.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="field_Description">File Description </label>
         <textarea tab-index="1" class="form-control" style="height: 200px;"
            id="field_Description" ng-maxlength="2000"
            ng-model="vm.Description"
            name="File Description"/>
         <div ng-if="myForm.Description.$invalid">
            <p class="help-block"
               ng-if="myForm.Description.$error.maxlength">
               This field cannot be longer than 2000 characters.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

As the UI designed are in column design, so if the design if divided into two parts and each part have four combo boxes, then they are added as :

Div1

- Field1
- Field3
- Field5
- Field7

Div2

- Field2
- Field4
- Field6
- Field7

Then both div are added as :

```
<div class="col-sm-12"> ... Div1 ...Div2.. </div>
```

I need tab movement as Field1 -> Field2, Field3 -> Field4....Field7 -> Field8

But the cursor moves as Field1-> Field3 -> Field5 -> Field7 then Field2 -> Field4 -> Field6 -> Field8

As I have given tab-index as left to right direction as they designed but the cursor focus always moving in top to down as they are added in the design.

How to set tab index and focus in left to right direction then to down without reformatting the ui ?

Is there any way to manually adding tab-index without design changes?

Answer (score 1):

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UkklIkhDrbvj5M8GZfuQ?p=preview)

For more info go through [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Div1</h1>
      <div tabindex="1">1fdsfsdf</div>
      <div tabindex="2">3fdsfsdd</div>
      <div tabindex="3">5fdsfsdf</div>
      <div tabindex="4">7fdsfsdd</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1>Div2</h1>
      <div tabindex="1">2fdsfsdf</div>
      <div tabindex="2">4fdsfsdd</div>
      <div tabindex="3">6fdsfsdf</div>
      <div tabindex="4">8fdsfsdd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <strong>Note: </strong>You can change display style of container in styles.css
</body>

</html>
```

**css**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: How to move to first index when reaches to last element i.e. if I reached to  8fdsfsdd then the cursor should move to 1fdsfsdf element. ?

Comment: You can't do that just by pressing tab key. Even that is not needed I think. But when you press tab again and again, once the url box browser focused then the loop will continue and also that is not a good practice as well

Comment: But in my sample tab-index start with 0 and it takes to first when reaches to last one. This is the main requirement to set to first when tab is pressed on last one.

Comment: Be cautiuos with `tabindex` as the browser url box is also with `tabindex=0`. So better start with `tabindex=1` in your situation

Comment: I need to set to first element when reached to last one, staring tab-index from zero in both div not working fine, it skip some elements in left-to-right order. Is there any way to navigate left-to-right then on first.

Comment: If you keep `tabindex=0` to some element and then it will get focused on first tab click. then if there are other elements with `tabindex=0` they will get focused on next tab click. and so on... In this case, if you set `tabindex=0` for one element and `>0` for other elements then after focusing the element with `tabindex=0` the browser url box will get focused and then the other elements will get focused.